# Using 2013 msbuild in program with Project.Build

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2013

Our tests use [Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.Project.Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd234329(v=vs.121).aspx) to build projects.

Works fine for VS 2010 & 2012. Trouble is in VS 2013, it picks up msbuild from

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe

ver 4.0.30319.18408
```

instead of from VS 2013

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe

ver 12.0.21005.1
```

Is there any method to ask it to pick up the VS 2013 msbuild?
May be adding to the .proj file or setting an environment value before calling the build method?

Answer (score 3):

**MSBuild and its Toolset now Version with Visual Studio**

*We plan to evolve our build tools with each version of Visual Studio from now on. Each release of the Micrsoft® Build Tools will have a new version of MSBuild, the VB/C# Compilers, and Toolset. They will all version together. Visual Studio will use its corresponding version of MSBuild exclusively. For instance, Visual Studio 2013 will exclusively use MSBuild 2013 and ToolsVersion=”12.0”. To align with Visual Studio’s versioning we have updated MSBuild’s assembly version from 4.0 to 12.0 as well.*

And a link to the visual studio team page, with a few additional defaults to check

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2013/07/24/msbuild-is-now-part-of-visual-studio.aspx

**however 4.0 and version 12 are the same; re-versioned to support the visual studio version number format**

Answer (score 0):

from:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework_version_history#.NET_Framework_4.5

*//Quote//
.NET Framework 4.5 was released on 15 August 2012.,[27] a set of new or improved features were added into this version.[28] The .NET Framework 4.5 is only supported on Windows Vista or later.[29][30] The .NET Framework 4.5 uses Common Language Runtime 4.0, with some additional runtime features.[31]
//End Quote*

Since 4.5 is an "upgrade" to the 4.0 library......."C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\" is where I would expect it to find its version of MsBuild.exe.

Are the MSBuild.Exe (that you list) different?

You could experiment with overriding the

```
 <Message Text=" MSBuildBinPath  = $(MSBuildBinPath)" />
```

property.

Comment: Can you post that version number (in full) ?  Now I"m curious.

Comment: hi sorry for the delay, been multitasking! Updated the question with the version numbers. Thanks.